# SMS receiver crash

Tags: android, sms

Hello to all I have getting some issue in this code

This is my Main Activity where i click on Add button to show my SMs Screen but it always crash

```
package com.example.project.ultimatesmsblocker;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 

    {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    } public void show(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmsReceiver.class);
       startActivity(intent); }}
```

---

THis is my sms receiver class

```
package com.example.project.ultimatesmsblocker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by GhulamMustafa on 6/21/2016.
 */

    public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in--
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
          SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
          String str = "SMS from ";
             if (bundle != null)
             {
                 //---retrieve the SMS message received--
                      Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                      msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                      for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                          msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                          if (i==0) {
                              //---get the sender address/phone number--
                                    str += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                                    str += ": ";
                                    }
                                    //---get the message body--
                                       str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                      }
                 //---display the new SMS message--
                         Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //---prevent this SMS message from being broadcasted--
                          abortBroadcast();
                 Log.d("SMSReceiver", str);
             }
        try {
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(context,"No Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }}}
```

---

This is Android Manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.project.ultimatesmsblocker">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BlockList">

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

When i compile it and click on add button it always crash kindly help as soon as possible .. I will be very thankful to u..

Comment: Please post the logcat output.

Comment: Please post the stack trace so we can see what the crash is.

Comment: You can't call `startActivity()` with an `Intent` with a `BroadcastReceiver` as the target class, because it's not an `Activity`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to show my sms screen after clicking add button so for that i have to use an activity class???  Mike M

Comment: What "sms screen"? A `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't have a UI, so it's not that. Yes, you have to use an `Activity`.

Comment: But if i use another activity it doesn't show any message that is to be received

Comment: You have to handle displaying the messages yourself. It's not going to do it automagically.

Comment: That is my question how i can display my message on that activity or screen???